# routing in canjs not working as links are not getting an href value

Tags: routes, canjs

I am new to canjs and following the tutorials on canjs site. I am using webpack to create a sample canjs page.

```
import { Component, stacheRouteHelpers } from "can";

Component.extend({
    tag: "my-app",
    view: `
        <a href="{{ routeUrl(page='home') }}">Home</a>
        <a href="{{ routeUrl(page='tasks') }}">Tasks</a>
    `,
    ViewModel: {
    }
});
```

When I see in the page, it's not routing to the home. Infact href value is not coming in output like below.

```
<a href="">Home</a>
```

console shows the following warning

```
MyAppView:3: Unable to find key "routeUrl()".
```

Comment: I think webpack is stacheRouteHelpers because it's not used directly in that file (the template doesn't count).  Is there a way to tell webpack not to treeshake a module?

Answer (score 0):

Like Justin mentioned, I think webpack is tree-shaking `stacheRouteHelpers` out of the build.

I think you can work around [the issue](https://github.com/canjs/can-stache-route-helpers/issues/20) by doing the following:

```js
import { Component, stache, stacheRouteHelpers } from "can";

stache.addHelper(stacheRouteHelpers);
```